# Installing keras in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, failed-installation

I'm trying to install keras in rstudio Version 1.2.5033. I was planning to use Python 3.7 in Anaconda environment. However, I have problems with when I tried to run the following code

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential()
```

I received the following error

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       NA
                     (right here) ------^
```

I tried to check the python configs with the following code

```
library(reticulate)
py_config()
```

but also received the same error message

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       NA
                     (right here) ------^
```

I tried to set the python to the anaconda environment using the following code

```
reticulate::use_python("C:/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow", required=TRUE)
```

and when I run

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential()
```

I received the following message

```
running command '"C:/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/python.exe" "C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/reticulate/config/config.py"' had status 1running command '"C:/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/python.exe" "C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/reticulate/config/config.py"' had status 1running command '"C:/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/python.exe" "C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/reticulate/config/config.py"' had status 1Error in python_config(python_version, required_module, python_version,  : 
  Error 1 occurred running C:/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/python.exe
```

I have tried using

```
install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
install_github("rstudio/keras")
```

but it still resulted in errors.

I have searched all sources but I have not found anyone with the same problem as me. Can someone help me with this.
My session info is below.

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.14

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        rstudioapi_0.11   knitr_1.28        magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.5.1     devtools_2.2.2    pkgload_1.0.2    
 [8] R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.5       fansi_0.4.1       tools_3.6.3       pkgbuild_1.0.6    xfun_0.12         sessioninfo_1.1.1
[15] cli_2.0.2         withr_2.1.2       ellipsis_0.3.0    remotes_2.1.1     assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.25     rprojroot_1.3-2  
[22] crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.4.2    callr_3.4.2       fs_1.3.2          ps_1.3.2          curl_4.3          testthat_2.3.2   
[29] memoise_1.1.0     glue_1.3.1        compiler_3.6.3    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.5   prettyunits_1.1.1 jsonlite_1.6.1
```

```
devtool::session info
- Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
 ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252 
 tz       Asia/Bangkok                
 date     2020-03-17                  

- Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 backports     1.1.5   2019-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 base64enc     0.1-3   2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 callr         3.4.2   2020-02-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 curl          4.3     2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 devtools      2.2.2   2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ellipsis      0.3.0   2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 fs            1.3.2   2020-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 generics      0.0.2   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 jsonlite      1.6.1   2020-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 keras       * 2.2.5.0 2019-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 knitr         1.28    2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 pkgbuild      1.0.6   2019-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 processx      3.4.2   2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ps            1.3.2   2020-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 Rcpp          1.0.3   2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 remotes       2.1.1   2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 reticulate  * 1.14    2019-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rlang         0.4.5   2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 rstudioapi    0.11    2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 tensorflow    2.0.0   2019-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tfruns        1.4     2018-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 usethis       1.5.1   2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 whisker       0.4     2019-08-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 xfun          0.12    2020-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 zeallot       0.1.0   2018-01-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)

[1] C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.6
[2] D:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library
```